# The ID field of the BaseEntity keeps increasing when insert a new data to different tables in MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, n-tier-architecture

I was making a MVC project using Unit Of Work and Repository. I Separated my Models, Controllers and Mapping , etc... into different libraries in the solution. While i was working with the Base Entity, i happened to encounter an issue that the ID that i used for multiple tables that based on the Base Entity increases in this scenario. When i insert a new data to Table A, the ID auto increases for EX : 1, but when i insert a new data to Table B, the ID increases its value of Value A and the first Data of Table B has ID's value of 2. How can i manage to separate the ID between tables to increase by the TABLE's current value instead of the BASE ENTITY's current value that the TABLE is based on ? 
Here is my Base Entities :

```
namespace Thaco_Model.Model
{
    public interface IBaseEntities
    {
        long ID { get; set; }
        String name { get; set; }
    }
    public class BaseEntities : IBaseEntities
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsDelete { get; set; }
        public int creator_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> editor_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> created_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> edited_Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my table A

```
namespace Thaco_Model.Model
{
    [Table("ValueFlag")]
    public class Value_Flag :BaseEntities
    {
    }
}
```

This is my table B :

```
namespace Thaco_Model.Model
{
    [Table("DefinedValue")]
    public class Defined_Value : BaseEntities
    {
        public long flag_ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my Repository :

```
namespace Data
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntities
    {
        private readonly DB_ver_5 context;
        private IDbSet<T> entities;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        public Repository(DB_ver_5 context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
        public T GetById(object id)
        {
            return this.Entities.Find(id);
        }

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
                }
                this.Entities.Add(entity);
                this.context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {

                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        errorMessage += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                        validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
            }
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
                }
                this.context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                        validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }

                throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
            }
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
                }

                this.Entities.Remove(entity);
                this.context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {

                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        errorMessage += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                        validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
            }
        }
        public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Entities;
            }
        }

        private IDbSet<T> Entities
        {
            get
            {
                if (entities == null)
                {
                    entities = context.Set<T>();
                }
                return entities;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your code. Base entity and at least one child class

Comment: What i want to archive is the Table A and the Table B has both Data's ID start from 1, not count based on each other current ID, and one more thing,  i don't use any foreign key in this model, and i use Code-first to create these Entities

Comment: You cane remove usings from samples it takes space only. Ok and how how does your base repository looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is normal, prior to EF.

You have a base entity class that has a primary key. When you make this class a parent of others, Entity Framework is considering that you do want to share properties. If you take a look at your database, you should see that `ValueFlag` has no `ID`. Same goes for `DefinedValue`. It's because your shared properties must be in a table called `BaseEntity`. By doing that, EF enables the possibility of "sharing properties".

If you want to have seperated ID, you need to change the EF behavior from TPT to TPC : https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Also, please consider that inheritance is usually nice and good enough for small tables. When it comes to large data, it shows some performance problems (aside of EF "normal" performances problems) due to the multiplication of JOINS.

Comment: I don't know if you call that they don't have the ID on either of the tables, but i want to approach the " Don't Repeat Yourself " like there are some Entities that repeated multiple times in different Table so i tried to use the relationship to give every tables that have the Identical entities those BaseEntities to make it easier and shorter the codes.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say... Either way, databases and "source code" are two different things. Most of the time, you can't apply the rules and principles of one on the other. So, even if "don't repeat yourself" can be achieved in a database context, it comes with a price. In your case, the price to pay is to share the Identity (and other things, but that's not the main point). If you don't want that, you have to use another approch, like the TPC, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i really Appreciate that